# How to declare variable in index.php and access in every controller opencart php

Tags: php, opencart

I have the following piece of code to check if the API is working or not:

```
try {
    $api = new SoapClient(API_URL,array(
       'exceptions' => true,
    ));
    $api_conn = $api->queryCategories(array('params' => array('usertoken' => USER_TOKEN)));
    $registry->set('api',$api);
    $api_status = true;
} catch( SoapFault $e) {
    $api_status = false;
}
```

I am trying to set status for API as `true` or `false` so that I can use it wherever I need but I am unable to access `$api_status` in any of the controllers.

Where should I declare it to access globally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the $GLOBALS variable

```
$GLOBALS['api_status'] = $api_status;
```

in another php script...

```
if($GLOBALS['api_status']){
    //....
}
```

see
http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: Any other way of doing thing through Opencart

Answer (score 0):

I guess if you want any variable available globally in Every controller go to

```
yourproject/system/engine/controller.php
```

here you can define variable

```
eg: protected $api_status = 1;
```

Now you can use the value of `$api_status` from any controller using

```
$this->api_status;
```